# Characterization of normal operators on Hilbert space as function of a self-adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

My question :
Suppose T is a normal operator on a Hilbert space H. Show that there exists a self-adjoint operator S on H such that T=f(S), where f is continuous function from spectrum of S into S.

My approach to the problem was to find out an operator S and show that the $C^*$ algebra generated by $I$ and $S$ includes T. Then, continuous functional calculus would prove the result. So my first guess was to choose $S=(T+T^*)/2$. However, I have been unable to show that T is the limit of some polynomial in S.

Is my intuition about the problem correct? In that case, please provide some suggestions regarding how to show that T is in the unital sub-algebra generated by S?

Comment: What do you know about maximal Abelian selfadjoint algebras?

Comment: I have studied operator theory till functional calculus for normal operators on a C* algebra. So, I feel that the maximal Abelian self adjoint algebra will be a C* subalgebra where I can apply the functional calculus.

Comment: @user252334: The argument in the question cannot work. Let $T=I+iW $ for any nontrivial selfadjoint operator  $W $. Then $S=I $ and $T $ does not belong to $C^*(S)=\mathbb C I$.

Comment: @TrialAndError: how would you use a masa here? The fact that masas are singly generated will easily give you a Borel $f$, but not a continuous one.

Comment: @MartinArgerami : Yes, I glossed over the requirement of continuous.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thanks for pointing out the flaw.

Answer (score 1):

Idea: $\mathbb{R}^m\cong\mathbb{R}^n$

Choose function:*
$$\eta\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C},\mathbb{R}):\quad \vartheta\circ\eta=\mathrm{id}$$
Construct operator:
$$S:=\eta(N):\quad S=S^*$$
By Borel calculus:
$$N=\mathrm{id}(N)=\vartheta(\eta(N))=\vartheta(S)$$
**Note discontinuity!*

Comment: I haven't yet studied about Borel calculus. Can you please explain it in a way more accessible to someone with a basic introduction to Operator algebras?

Comment: Sure: The Borel calculus is the extension of the continuous calculus to Borel functions. Now the problem is that you won't find a continuous function with the relation to the identity. That is because of topological reasons like connectedness. But one can still find a Borel function that satisfies the relation to the identity. That is all euclidean spaces agree in the category of Borel spaces. Let us now call the Borel calculus simply functional calculus...

Comment: ... For the functional calculus it holds $\overline{\eta(N)+\vartheta(N)}=(\eta+\vartheta)(N)$, $\lambda\eta(N)=(\lambda\eta)(N)$, $\overline{\vartheta(N)\eta(N)}=(\vartheta\eta)(N)$ etc. *and* also $\vartheta(\eta(N))=(\vartheta\circ\eta)(N)$. But that is what we need namely $N=\vartheta(S)$. So we choose a Borel function with $\vartheta\circ\eta=\mathrm{id}$.

Comment: @user252334: Is it clearer now?

Comment: Sorry for being late in replying. Yes, I understand your solution now. But I have another question about your comment. I suppose $\bar{\eta{N}}$ stand for the * in the algebra. For the Borel calculus to agree with the continuous calculus over continuous functions, shouldn't we have  $\overline{\eta(N)}=\eta(N^{*})$ in general? Or was the comment for the specific function $\eta$ used here which maps into $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: No the overline means taking the closure as for unbounded measurables the domain may decrease. So for example in general you have only $\mathcal{D}(\eta(N)+\vartheta(N))=\mathcal{D}\eta(N)\cap\mathcal{D}\vartheta(N)‌​\subseteq\mathcal{D}(\eta+\vartheta)(N)$. Thus $\eta(N)+\vartheta(N)\subseteq(\eta+\vartheta)(N)$ in the sense of operators. However it turns out that this is merely an issue of unclosed operators. That is $\overline{\eta(N)+\vartheta(N)}=(\eta+\vartheta)(N)$.

Comment: So the **full** algebraic list becomes: $\overline{\eta(N)+\vartheta(N)}=(\eta+\vartheta)(N)$, $\lambda\eta(N)=(\lambda\eta)(N)$ as well as $\overline{\eta(N)\vartheta(N)}=(\eta\vartheta)(N)$, $\eta(N)^*=\eta^*(N)$, $\eta(N)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\eta}(N)$ and also $\vartheta(\eta(N))=(\vartheta\circ\eta)(N)$.

Comment: And besides for late reply never mind ;)